# configuring gitlab project for https access

Tags: clone, gitlab

I have created a project in gitlab called git clone test. In the advanced setting feature i can see that cloning can be done only by git clone git@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:git_clone_test.git. I want to clone using https protocol.
So i tried the following
git remote set-url origin https://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/git_clone_test.git
verified
git remote -v
origin  https://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/git_clone_test.git (fetch)
origin  https://xxx.xx.xxx.xxxgit_clone_test.git (push)

[edit]: gitlab.yaml has https turned on on port 443

But the following command 
$ env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/git_clone_test.git
Cloning into 'git_clone_test'...
Gives the error:

fatal: https://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/git_clone_test.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

I think problem lies in the fact that gitlab does not allow me to change git clone field in advanced settings. Perhaps a server setting needs to change?

We are using gitlab (git+gitolite) on nginx server.

We are trying to use https access as this server is behind a firewall, and the client cannot clone it. They can see the web interface and and download files from that interface, but git operations pose a problem. We think that changing access to https might solve this problem
Any pointers would help

thanks
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this issue by upgrading to latest version of gitlab which supports https access in a pretty straightforward manner

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have forgotten some small changes within your [gitlab.yml](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-4-stable/config/gitlab.yml.example#L19-L20) configuration.

To use HTTPS you also have to change the config file as follows

```
# https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-4-stable/config/gitlab.yml.example#L19-L20
port: 80
https: false
```

change to:

```
port: 443
https: true
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Nope this change does not help. It was actually already in place.